# On click, highlight a tables column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

With my table, the user can sort the results ascending and descending. I need to make it to where when they click on the header button to sort that column, it changes the background of all the columns (directly underneath that header column) to change the background color... Here's my code thus far:
Here's the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.move_right {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.center-text {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.bottom_center_text {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
#nav_bottom {
    height: 0px; !important
}
#portfolio_header {
    Background-color: #5E90B3;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
table#bin, table#fallen, table#growth, table#turn { margin:10px 0; border:1px solid #ccc; }
th, td { padding:10px 7px; }
tr th { background:#ededed; color:#545454; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;}
#bin tr.even td { background:#e1eff1; }
#turn tr.even td { background:#f7f2d8; }
#fallen tr.even td { background:#f2dcbd; }
#growth tr.even td { background:#deefdc; }
td.title a { text-decoration:none; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold;}
#bin td.title { background:#5198a0; }
#fallen td.title { background:#e6a850; }
#turn td.title { background:#ebd870; }
#growth td.title { background:#6ab065; }
#bin td.title a { color:#182c2e; font-size:13px;}
#fallen td.title a { color:#352713;  font-size:13px;}

#turn td.title a { color:#37321a;  font-size:13px; }
#growth td.title a { color:#233d21;  font-size:13px;}
hr { border:2px dotted #ccc; border-bottom:none; }
#tooltip { position:absolute; z-index:3000; border:1px solid #111; background-color:#eee; padding:5px; }
#tooltip h3, #tooltip div, #tooltip p { margin:0; }


/*#bin tr.even td.click, th.click,*/ td.click, th.click
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
/*#bin tr.even td.hover, tr.hover,*/ td.hover, tr.hover
{
    background-color: #CCC;
}
/*#bin tr.even th.hover, tfoot td.hover,*/ th.hover, tfoot td.hover
{
    background-color: ivory;
}
/*#bin tr.even td.hovercell, th.hovercell,*/ td.hovercell, th.hovercell
{
    background-color: #abc;
}
/*#bin tr.even td.hoverrow, th.hoverrow,*/ td.hoverrow, th.hoverrow
{
    background-color: #6df;
}
</style>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="bin" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; padding-top: 20px;" width="10%" title="Sort by Symbol" id="row-1" data-column="1">Symbol <img src="/images/sort-arrow-up.jpg" title="Sort by Symbol" alt="Sort by Symbol" class="sort-right move-left bottom-image" id="image1"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:left;" width="20%" title="Sort by Company Name" id="row-2" data-column="2">Company<br><span class="move_right">Name</span> <img src="/images/sort-arrow-up.jpg" title="Sort by Company Name" alt="Sort by Company Name" class="sort-right move-left" id="image2"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="12%" title="Sort by Buy Date" id="row-3" data-column="3"><span class="center-text">Buy</span><br>Date <img title="Sort by Buy Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Buy Date" id="image3"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" title="Sort by Buy Price" id="row-4" data-column="4"><span class="center-text">Buy</span><br>Price &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Buy Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Buy Price" id="image4"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" title="Sort by Closed Price" id="row-5" data-column="5"><span class="center-text">Closed</span><br>Price &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Closed Price" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Closed Price" id="image5"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="9%" title="Sort by Closed Date" id="row-6" data-column="6"><span class="center-text">Closed</span><br>Date &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Closed Date" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Closed Date" id="image6"/></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="10%" title="Sort by Current Return" id="row-7" data-column="7"><span class="center-text">Total</span><br>Return &nbsp;<img title="Sort by Current Return" src="/images/sort-arrow.jpg" alt="Sort by Current Return" id="image7"/></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($buylist as $a) {
        $bg = ($c % 2) ? ' class="even"' : '';
        $direction = (is_numeric($a['creturn']) && $a['creturn'] >= 0) ? 'up_green' : 'down_red';
        $tick = (is_numeric($a['creturn']) && $a['creturn'] >= 0) ? '<img src="/images/icon_up.gif">' : '<img src="/images/icon_down.gif">';
        $tick2 = (is_numeric($a['cchange']) && $a['cchange'] >= 0) ? '<img src="/images/icon_up.gif">' : '<img src="/images/icon_down.gif">';   
        $tick3 = (is_numeric($a['final_return_pct']) && $a['final_return_pct'] >= 0) ? '<img src="/images/icon_up.gif">' : '<img src="/images/icon_down.gif">'; 
        $type = '';
        $entry_price = (is_numeric($a['buyprice'])) ? '$'.$a['buyprice'] : '&ndash;';
        $sold_price = (is_numeric($a['sold_price'])) ? '$'.$a['sold_price'] : '&ndash;';
        $total_return= sprintf("%.02f", (($a['sold_price'] - $a['buyprice'])/$a['buyprice']) * 100);
?>
            <tr<?=$bg;?>>
                <td data-column="1"><b><a href="/gamechangers/getaquote/?symbolsearch=<?php echo $a['symbol']; ?>"><?=$a['symbol'];?></a></b><?=$type;?></td>
                <td data-column="2"><?=$a['name'];?></td>
                <td align="center" data-column="3"><?=$a['buydate'];?></td>
                <td align="center" data-column="4"><?=$entry_price;?></td>
                <td align="center" data-column="5"><?php echo $sold_price; ?></td>
                <td align="center" data-column="6"><?=$a['sold_date'];?></td>
                <td align="center" data-column="7"><?php echo $total_return; ?>%</td>
            </tr>
<?php
        $c++;
    }
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried using a plugin, but that was to no avail because I am having PHP grab content from the database and directly feed it into the table. Side note: When PHP grabs the content from the database, it is alternating the color of the rows in the table from white to blue.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what javascript have you tried?

Comment: I have been manly trying to mess around with this plugin (example 4) http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html @JasonP

Comment: [Did you check this](http://datatables.net/) ?

Comment: Yeah but that does to much.. We already have a table made, designed and everything.. (using that plugin won't work with our PHP).. @RCV

Answer (score 3):

I would assign every `<td>` and `<th>` a `data-column` attribute indicating which column it is. Then on click of the `<th>`, grab the `data-column` attribute of the header and use jQuery (or similar library) to change the color of all table cells with that `data-column` attribute.

Example table markup:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="1">Column 1</th>
      <th data-column="2">Column 2</th> // etc ....
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-column="1">contents</td>
      <td data-column="2">contents</td> // etc...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '#table th', function(){

  // Grab the column number
  var column = $(this).attr('data-column');

  // Reset any highlighted columns
  $('#table td').removeClass('highlighted'); 

  // Set all columns with the same column number to have the highlight class
  $('#table td[data-column='+column+']').addClass('highlighted');

})
```

Hope this helps!

Best,
Andrew

Comment: How can I change this to not change the color of the header column, but only the columns underneath of it? @Andrew

Comment: @PixelReaper Just don't put the `data-column` attribute on the ths in the `thead` section.

Comment: I was just thinking that, but this way wont work. The table rows are being made in a foreach() that is setting an class="even" to change the background on every other row, therefor making it impossible to add a data-column="" in a incrementing value. @Sébastien

Comment: I don't see how those two things are related. Can you modify the foreach loop or not?

Comment: It's complicated to explain, but no I cannot currently make changes to it. @Sébastien

Comment: Okay I can now and I added the data-column to each row.. Could you modify that JavaScript to where it applies a CSS class instead of adding the CSS inline? I need to override the CSS that is already stylizing the table @Sébastien

Comment: @PixelReaper I've updated my answer to add classes instead of inline styling; I also updated it so it only highlights the column beneath the header and not the header itself.

Comment: Whenever the pages loads up, the class is already attached to the td, it doesn't require you to click it. Also, when clicking it again, it doesn't remove the class. @Andrew

Comment: @PixelReaper Can you share the Javascript you're using? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this pretty easily with JQuery, using `.index()` and `:eq()`, without having to change your current HTML at all.

When you click to do the sort, after everything is sorted, grab the position of the clicked `<th>` in the row using this:

```
var colNum = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
```

. . . though, this is assuming that the click event is bound to the `<th>` itself.  If it is tied to a lower-level element, you'd have to modify the code a little bit, to this:

```
var parentTH = $(this).closest("th");
var colNum = parentTH.parent().children().index(parentTH);
```

Once you have the index of the `<th>` in the row, you can then select all of the `<td>` tags that are in the same positions of their row, like this:

```
var selectedColCells = $("#bin tr").find("td:eq(" + colNum + ")");
```

Once you have those, you can add a class or change the style directly for each one (I'd recommend using a class   :)   ).  You will also want to clear the class/style from all `<td>` tags in the table, each time, so that it resets to the default "unsorted" look.

On side note, if you used a `<colgroup>` in your table, with a `<col>` for each column, you could use the same logic, but you would only have to update the selected `<col>` with the class/style, instead of each `<td>` in the column.

**Edit:** fixed a minor issue in the logic for finding the "colNum" value, when the click event is tied to an element below the `<th>` level.

Comment: I am not entirely following what you're saying. I updated the code to include the foreach that is making more rows into the table as well. Could you please add what you're saying to my code? @talemyn

Comment: My code wasn't a PHP approach, but a JQuery approach that was intended to be tied to the click event that leads to the table being resorted.  Looking at your PHP code, it looks like you are actually reloading the page when you sort the data.  Is that true?  If so, I'll need to modify my answer.

Comment: Nope--page does not refresh when everything is sorted. I also added the CSS @talemyn

Comment: Oh, so where is the JavaScript or JQuery code that you are using to handle the click that causes the column to be sorted . . . I don't see that and that is what would need to be updated.

Comment: We are using a whole separate plugin for that function.. IS there anyway we can add it without that code? @talemyn

Comment: Hmmmm . . . that's gonna be tricky.  You need some event to trigger the JS/JQuery to update.  If you can't piggyback on the click event, then there are only two options: (1) use the PHP code to add styles/classes to the `<td>` elements of the sort column of the table, as it is updating the sort, or (2) implement a "watcher" function in JS/JQuery to look for the table content to change and trigger the style update when it does (which means JS code constantly running int the background, waiting for the off chance that the table gets sorted).